# If $F[x]$ is a principal domain does $F$ have to be necessarily a field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

If $F$ is a field, then $F[x]$ is a principal ideal domain.

> Conversely, if $F[x]$ is a principal domain does $F$ have to be necessarily a field?

**My Thoughts:** Suppose instead of $F$, we take the set of polynomials $R[x]$ over a commutative ring $R$ with unity.

Then, suppose $I$ is an ideal of $R[x]$. Let $g(x) \in I$ such that $g(x)$ is the polynomial of the lowest degree in $I$.

Then: $ \langle g(x) \rangle \subseteq I .......... (1)$

Let $f(x) \in I$. Then $f(x) = p(x)g(x) + r(x)~~|~~p(x),r(x) \in R[x], \deg r(x) < \deg g(x)$

Since, $I$ is an ideal $\implies f(x) - p(x)g(x) = r(x) \in I$

But, $g(x)$ is of the lowest degree in $I \implies r(x) = 0 \implies f(x) \in \langle g(x)  \rangle \implies I \subseteq \langle g(x)  \rangle ......(2)$

Then from $(1),(2) : I = \langle g(x) \rangle$

Does the Presence of zero divisors in $R[x]$ really make a difference? The only advantage I see is that if there are no zero divisors in $R[x]$ then $I=\{0\} \implies I= \langle 0  \rangle$.

But, every ideal contains the zero element. Why is there the condition of a field specifically given in textbooks for $F[x]$ to be a principal ideal domain?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: How do you propose to divide $\,x\,$ by $\,2\,$ in $\,\Bbb Z[x],\, $ in (fruitless) attempt to prove $\,(x,2)\,$ is principal?

Comment: I see where I went wrong. Thank you :)

Comment: I believe it can be improved to from "field" to "division ring", if we change the conclusion "PID" to "all ideals are principal, but not asking integral domain".

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes it does. For if not the ideal $(x)$ would not be maximal, and every prime ideal in PID is maximal. This goes through the characterization of a maximal ideal as $M\subseteq R$ is maximal iff $R/M$ is a field.

In our case it's easy to see that:

$$F[x]/(x)\cong F$$

So the result is pretty immediate.

---

If you'd like the proof of "PID implies all (non-zero) prime ideals are maximal." It's pretty straightforward:

*Proof:*  Let $\mathfrak{p}=(p)$ be a non-zero prime ideal of a commutative ring, $R$ with $1$. then if $\mathfrak{p}\subseteq M\subseteq R$, then if $M=(x)$ we have that $x|p$ hence is either a unit or $p$ itself by definition of a prime.

---

**Addendum (where you went wrong):**  You do not necessarily have a division algorithm in an arbitrary polynomial ring, $R[x]$, since $R$ not a field means that the coefficients are not all units (i.e. the ring is not Euclidean). Take $R=\Bbb Z$, then you do not have the desired factorization with only integer polynomials for something like $3x$ and $2x$, since the difference cannot be made to have lower degree.

This generalizes to any non-field since you can find some non-unit somewhere to pull the same thing on.

Comment: Thanks. Can you please tell where I could have gone wrong in the proof above.

Comment: Further, PIDs are precisely the UFDs of dimension $\le 1,\,$ i.e. UFDs where every nonzero prime ideal is maximal.

Comment: To see where your proof goes wrong, look at it in the special case of the following easy counterexample: $R=\mathbb Z$ and $I$ is the ideal generated by $2$ and $x$.

Comment: Ohhh .. I missed that :( . Thank you for your comments :)

Comment: @VHP glad to help. I think I once wondered this myself early in my undergraduate career and was happy to learn the answer as well.

Comment: *Non-zero* prime ideals in PIDs are maximal =]