# If $F$ is a field then every ideal in $F[x]$ is a principal ideal.

Tags: field-theory, ideals

I have got no clue of how to start with the problem .Now I know that an ideal is a kernel of a ring homorphism but why would it be a principal ideal in $F[x]$.What is the intuition behind this ?(I would like to know why is it happening instead of a formal proof)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If $F$ be a field, then $F[x]$ is a principal ideal domain. Does $F$ have to be necessarily a field?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/873088/if-f-be-a-field-then-fx-is-a-principal-ideal-domain-does-f-have-to-be)

Comment: It is because $(f,g)=(\gcd(f,g))$ and the RHS ideal is larger than $(f)$ iff $\gcd(f,g)$ has lower degree than $f$